# How to format an image and vcard when using foundation accordion list

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

i am making a list that has names of people using an accordion function. when the user clicks on the person they want the dropdown content will have their image and vcard. how can i format the content so the image is on the right side and then the vcard on the left next to it? i am using foundation that is built in already. thanks

```
 <div class="accordion-content">

            <img src="http://thumb9.shutterstock.com/display_pic_with_logo/1294/108451796/stock-photo-friendly-male-doctor-at-the-gym-smiling-108451796.jpg" alt="PCP" style="width:304px;height:228px">
            <ul class="vcard">
                <li class="fn">Gaius Baltar</li>
                 <li class="street-address">123 Colonial Ave.</li>
                 <li class="locality">Caprica City</li>
                <li><span class="state">Caprica</span>, <span class="zip">12345</span></li>
                 <li class="email"><a href="#">g.baltar@example.com</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
```

Comment: `style="float: right"` on the image?

Answer (score 0):

As bigbobr stated the below should work.

```
<img style="width:304px;height:228px;float:right;" src="http://thumb9.shutterstock.com/display_pic_with_logo/1294/108451796/stock-photo-friendly-male-doctor-at-the-gym-smiling-108451796.jpg" alt="PCP">
```